# Как поменять цвет диалога?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment, android-style, android-themes

Есть диалог `BottomSheetDialogFragment` и тема `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`. Нужно сделать задний фон диалога таким же как у активити.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Гайд](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md#theming-bottom-sheets) предлагает изменить `backgroundTint` у `Widget.Material3.BottomSheet.Modal`, который по умолчанию ссылается на `colorSurface`. В теме `android:colorBackground` и `colorSurface` одинаковые. Итоговый цвет диалога будто смешивается с другим цветом и отличается от целевого. Вероятно потому что это `tint`.

В стандартной теме также есть `background=@null`, но его изменение ничего не делает. Полагаю причина в [комментарии](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/attrs.xml) к `backgroundTint`. Но что такое `shape theming` и как его отключить так и не понял.

```
<!-- Background color used by the BottomSheetBehavior background drawable when shape theming is enabled. 
Accepts a ColorStateList or ColorInt. 
If shape theming is not enabled, android:background should instead be utilized 
to set the background resource. -->
<attr name="backgroundTint"/>
```

```
<color name="md_theme_light_background">#FFFBFE</color>
<color name="md_theme_light_surface">#FFFBFE</color>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Andy" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_light_surface</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">true</item>

    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/App.ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="App.ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/App.Widget.Material3.BottomSheet</item>
</style>

<style name="App.Widget.Material3.BottomSheet" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/App.ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.TopRounded</item>
</style>
```